# Is my M1 chip rejecting my Nix Build commands?

Tags: build, macos-big-sur, nix, nixos

I was trying to run a Nix command to build a project:

`nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library`

and I received this error!

```
error: attribute 'aarch64-darwin' missing, at /nix/store/cyfj6bd0n0ckvkm67mhjyg1qcvrfgsg9-source/artifact.nix:11:10
```

Is 'aarch64-darwin' referring to 64 bit architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your M1 chips is not rejecting your builds, but some Nix expression is not prepared for M1 yet.

`plutus` was written by IOHK iirc, so you can check with them what's the status of M1 support for their software. If they don't already have a GitHub issue or other communication about it, it may be helpful to tell them the output of, say, `ls /nix/store/cyfj6bd0n0ckvkm67mhjyg1qcvrfgsg9-source` as context for the error message when you report the issue. I'm sure they'd like to improve the error if you mention it; they have to edit that code anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to run Nix build through Rosetta 2 or no?

Comment: Yes, this should work. You can pass `--option system x86_64-darwin` to use this. Make sure `extra-platforms = x86_64-darwin aarch64-darwin` in your `nix.conf`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I changed the nix conf to use the x86_64-darwin architecture. So basically I edited the /etc/nix/nix.conf and leave it like this:

```
substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
# system = aarch64-darwin
system = x86_64-darwin
extra-platforms = x86_64-darwin aarch64-darwin
```

And the just run:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.nix
```

To load the new pkgs related to the new architecture. The source that I used is:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/mmzut6/macos_plutus_playground_build_instructions/
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/95903#issuecomment-869041761

Comment: I would recommend to leave the `system` setting at the native architecture. You can add `--option system x86_64-darwin` when needed. If cardana is your only use case, perhaps it's easier to make intel default though, for now.

Answer (score 1):

These were my error messages for the M1 processor:

error: experimental Nix feature 'flakes' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features flakes' to override
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

error: attribute 'aarch64-darwin' missing

This is the command that worked for me:

````
```GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-shell --extra-experimental-features flakes  --option system x86_64-darwin
```
````